# C++ Linked List insertion node and pointer in struct

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, new-operator, nodes

I am trying to insert some nodes. My implementation is based on the stanford tutorial. http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/103/LinkedListBasics.pdf

And the following is my code.

```
 struct node
 {
      int p_data;
      struct node*   p_next;

      node(node* head, int data)
      {
            p_next = head;
            p_data = data;
      }

      explicit node(int data)
      {
            p_next = nullptr;
            p_data = data;
      }
 }
```

And here is my insertion function

```
 node* insert_node(node* head, int data)
 {
      return new node(head, data);
 }
```

And what I want to do, I set up the list of 1, 2, 3 for initial and want to add more elements like 5, 6, 7. Following is my try but the insertion does not do anything. So I am only printing out 1, 2, 3. In the main function, I have...

```
  struct node* head     = new node(NULL);
  struct node* nodep_01 = new node(NULL);
  struct node* nodep_02 = new node(NULL);

  head->p_data = 1;
  head->p_next = nodep_01;

  nodep_01->p_data = 2;
  nodep_01->p_next = nodep_02;

  nodep_02->p_data = 3;
  nodep_02->p_next = nullptr;
```

So if I print this, I get 1, 2, 3. And then I try to insertion one more element of value 5, but it does not do anything.

```
  insert_node(head, 5);
```

Could anybody help me do this? I want to insert elements to this list... THanks in advance!

Comment: You might also be interested in my survey of linked list variants: http://www.rossbencina.com/code/singly-linked-list-data-structure-variants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert_node(head, 5);
```

should be:

```
head = insert_node(head, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should shift the Head too to the current node!!!

Currently your head points to node with data 1
After addition of node with data 5 your head is still at node with data 1

Your further additions are useless and it cause memory leak that you don't know

Look at Ross Bencina answer and put head = insert_node(head, 5); instead of calling only insert_node(head, 5);